# "choppy" page loads vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an app made with vue.js. My issue is that on the initial load, it can be very "choppy" - It will first load text (in Arial, instead of my selected font), then load images (which offset the previously loaded text in an awkward manner), and then load my text font. Of course, this all happens in just ~2 seconds, but it looks quite unappealing.

Furthermore, things I want to run on mounted() -- supposed to run when the page is loaded and still -- run in the beginning of this choppy rendering. So my page loading is thus a mess. How can I make the loading smoother?

Comment: You can create a CSS preloader which covers the page and add it inside `<div id="app"></div>` in your static `index.html`.

Comment: Re: Fonts. Google "Flash of Unstyled Text" for many possible solutions. Re: Images. Add height and width attributes to the `<img>` tag if you can. Also see `v-cloak` in the [Vue docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak)

Comment: Are you using Vue template based on vue-cli?